# How to implement JS code to all months in SharePoint 2013 calendar

Tags: javascript

I am using a sharepoint 2013 calendar Page. Where I inserted a new webpart script editor webpar and written a code to shorten the Days names Like example if it is sunday I am using JS code in document.ready and making it to SUN.

This code is only working for Present Month December only. If I click any back or forward Months code not working all days are coming as default like sunday showing as sunday.

later I came to know that by clicking forward or backward it is using some ondemand script concept in sharepoint 2013.

Could any of you please help help me where exactly I need to wrie the js code so that it will work for all months while clicking.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is MDS you need to hook into it the official way with the  **asyncDeltaManager**

- https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sharepoint-javascript-context-development-part-4-the-way-of-the-async-delta-manager/
  Is a bit complex but has all the info
- http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/09/sharepoint-2013-execute-javascript-function-after-mds-load/
  Is a good starter

There are all kind of MDS events like:

```
asyncDeltaManager.add_beginRequest( function(){} );
asyncDeltaManager.add_pageLoaded( function(){} );
asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest( function(){} );
```

Comment: In mySharePoint Team Site the Minimal Download Strategy feature is not enabled. Its normal site. Please write a jquery code in document.ready in calendar page and click next month this jquery code will not work.

Comment: sorry, can't help with jQuery, never learned how to do that properly